# Why does magnetism penetrate all known materials

Tags: magnetic-fields

Does there exist a reason without complex mathematical descriptions that can account for the fact that there are no known materials that magnetism does not penetrate. I found a reference to Maxwell's Del dot B equals 0 which speaks of the inferance of no magnetic monopolies,  but aside from this unsatisfactory "answer" which does not explain the phenomenon in terms which I can understand, I can't find an answer.

Comment: *"there are no known materials that magnetism does not penetrate"* - sounds like you haven't heard about the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect)

Comment: Acuriousmind... I have in fact,  however this special case does not actually totally exclude the field, and breaks down at high field conditions. Doesn't help but appreciate the feedback

Comment: have a look at mu metal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal

Answer (score 2):

I think one should first reframe the question and ask,  *how do you prevent the penetration of magnetic fields in a solid in the first place?* As noted in another answer, there are no magnetic monopoles in nature, so the only possible way* is to block the field is to run a current in the material which generates a field that counteracts the applied magnetic field.

If the only way for a material to to block an external magnetic field is through a current, we should think about how that current can be sustained in time.  With the exception of superconductors, all materials have nonzero resistance. Therefore,  the current needed to block penetration of magnetic fields will *always* decay in time. Thus, in general,  there is no way to screen static magnetic fields in a material with nonzero resistance.

On the other hand, for alternating magnetic fields, most metals block magnetic fields just fine (provided they are thick compared to the skin depth) and the magnetic field does not penetrate except in an exponentially suppressed fashion. The key point here is Faraday's law which tells you that you need a changing magnetic field to generate a current.

*Note: You could also utilize the spin magnetic moment of elementary particles, but this fails for large magnetic fields that OP cares about (above 1 Tesla) except perhaps in neutron stars where the density is very high. Methods using mu metal and ordinary diamagnetism fall under this category.

Comment: Diamagnetic materials permanently repel magnetic fields too.

Comment: @Laff70 diamagnetic materials only repel a tiny fraction of external magnetic fields ( typically below 0.0001), with the exception of superconductors. Magnetic fields therefore can penetrate into diamagnets just fine.

Answer (score 0):

ACuriousMind is of course correct, in the area of superconducting materials, but for the rest of the material world, I have always thought it was because magnetic monopoles, as far we know, cannot exist.

You have the mathematical basis for this in your post, re the Maxwell equation quoted.

All magnetic field lines therefore have to begin and end on **some** particular material surface.

Comment: TaMe... This still provides no mechanism and is only inferred from Maxwell's equation. Is there a known answer or is this an example of the incompleteness therom of Godel?

Comment: **an example of the incompleteness therom**  You will have join the dots for me on that one.  I can't see the connection between the lack of a self consistent axiomatic mathematical framework and the question you asked. I am sure you have seen the video of Feynman trying to explain to a reporter that without math he would not even **try** to explain magnetism, (and even with math we can't).

Comment: So:  #1. I obviously ain't Feynman. #2. You asked for a non math description 3. I would argue that both logical and physical arguments give support to my answer, until we find a monopole. I honestly don't know enough to provide a full mechanism, but I bet you a virtual beer nobody else on this site does either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Since electrons have magnetic dipole moments an external field align this moments and form a magnetic field inside every material.

BTW the saturation of any material happens due to the finite number of available electrons which could be aligned.

The mentioned by ACuriousMind Messner effect takes place because according to Cooper the electrons unite to couples. By this they will be aligned with their opposite magnetic dipole moments and form a magnetic loop and for the external field it is easier to flow around the material instead of going through. This happens only at temperatures near 0 Kelvin, where the movement of electrons is strongly inhibited an Cooper pairs will be stable. And behind a certain strength of the external magnetic field the Cooper pairs will be destroyed.